# How can I use AntD FormInstance functions correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

I'm trying to validate user's input before they submit the form. How can I pass input field values to my validateInput function and if it returns false trigger and apply the following properties in the field `hasFeedback`, `validateStatus` and `help`

```
const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = form.useForm();
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Success:", values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };

  const validateInput = (input) => {
    const isEmailFormatValid = `regex...`;
    var check = input.match(validateFormat);
    return check
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Email"
        name="email"
        / * hasFeedback 
        validateStatus="warning"
        help="Invalid email format" */
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your email!",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your password!",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button block type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Form.Item>` prop `rules` is an array so you can add many rules to it.

If you want to check if the email input is not empty at the same time a valid email, you can do this:

```
<Form.Item
  label="Email"
  name="email"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: "Please input your email!",
    },
    {
      pattern: /your email regex here/,
      message: "Invalid email format",
    },
  ]}
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

No need for extra validation function. The error will automatically show if not meet the specified regex.

You can see all the rules of ant design input [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#Rule)

Comment: Ah that's easier. Do you know how I can apply a custom trigger error. Let's say only trigger once they move onto the next field. Currently it triggers straight away

Comment: Yes, just use this prop validateTrigger. It should be <Form.Item validateTrigger="onBlur">. The default value is onChange. You can also place it on the <Form> so it will apply to all of its <Form.Item>